# R - making objects null

Tags: r, loops, object, get

I had a large data set to create and did so in pieces. I created 50 data frames (F1:F50) and then I merged them together with:

```
for(i in 1:50) {x= get(paste0("F",i))
zF <- rbind.fill(zF,x)}
```

However now I'm trying to clear the other objects.

Once they are `NULL` I use

```
rm(list=names(which(sapply(globalenv(),is.null))))
```

Perhaps I could change `is.null()` to something like a pattern that describes my objects, but I thought it would be easier to just look through and make each `NULL` so I tried a few attempts:

```
> for(i in 1:56) {get(paste0("F",i))
     paste("F",i)=NULL}
Error in paste("F", i) = NULL : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object

> for(i in 1:56){get(paste0("F",i))=NULL}
    Error in get(paste0("F", i)) = NULL : 
      target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

So where the top loop worked but these failed implies to me that whilst `get` will give you the data to replicate (in the form of `x`) and then use, it does not allow me to change the actual object.

Is there a way to do this or is the solution using `rm`, I'd prefer the former as it opens up future changes to objects other than simply getting rid of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rm(list = ls(pattern = '^F'))
```

Remove all objects that match the pattern (in this case all objects that start with 'F')

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to use get or a similar function in case I want to do it that way. In my first code using x was sufficient but say for example I want to change the class of each object, Id have to create a load of dummies, rm the originals, then rename the dummies.

Comment: You can create a list of your objects using `ls(pattern = ..)` and then apply the function you need with the `apply` family to the `get`ted objects:
`my_list <- ls(pattern = '^F');

sapply(my_list, function(x) {as.numeric(get(x))})`